# Error showing Result Set Closed. how to remove it?

Tags: java

i have been working on this code since long .it is a code for generation of salary slip for the employee payroll management system using java netbeans IDE . This piece of code extracts data from the database regarding the deductions and allowances made by the employee.
  But, it keeps on giving me the result set closed error despite of having closed the result set before using it again.
Can you please help me rectify it..

the code is given here:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    String value1 = txt_id.getText();
    String value2 = txt_firstname.getText();
    String value3 = txt_surname.getText();
    String value4 = txt_design.getText();
    String value5 = txt_dept.getText();

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setSelectedFile(new File(value2 +" "+value3+"-SalarySlip.pdf"));
    int dialogResult = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
    if(dialogResult==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        try
        {
             String sql = "select * from Deductions where emp_id ='"+value1+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            String deduction = rs.getString(3);
            String reason = rs.getString(4);
            rs.close();
            pst.close();

            String sq = "select * from Allowance where emp_id = '"+value1+"'";

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sq);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            int sal = Integer.parseInt(txt_salary.getText());
            float total_allowance = Float.valueOf(rs.getString(8));
            float total_deduction =Float.valueOf(deduction);
            float total = (sal+total_allowance)-total_deduction;


            Document document = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(filePath));
            document.open();

             document.add(new Paragraph("PAY SLIP",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,30,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
             document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
             document.add(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));


       document.add(new Paragraph("EMPLOYEE DETAILS" ,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Name of the Employee :" + value2 +" "+value3,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Department :" + value5,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Designation :" + value4,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

       document.add(new Paragraph("SALARY" ,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Over Time :" + rs.getString(1),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Medical :" + rs.getString(2),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Bonus :" + rs.getString(3),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph( "Other :" + rs.getString(4),FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
       document.add(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

      document.add(new Paragraph("DEDUCTION" ,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph( "Amount Deducted : Rs. "+ total_deduction , FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph( "Deduction Details :" + reason,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

      document.add(new Paragraph("TOTAL PAYMENT" ,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph( "Total Earnings : Rs. " + total_allowance,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,15,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph( "Net Pay :" + total,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,10,Font.PLAIN,BaseColor.BLACK)));
      document.add(new Paragraph("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

      document.newPage();
      document.close();




        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

            }catch( Exception e)
            {

            }
        }






    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve the question. Without stacktrace added hardly anyone will even bother reading the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You must use try with resource for autoclose Statement or ResultSet.

For instance:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)){

    try(ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery()){
          .....
     }

}
catch(SQLException e){
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have closed the resultset as rs.close(), just remove that from there as well as pst.close from try block,as you are using try,catch please put this two code lines in finally block.

Answer (score 0):

You need not close your Statement and ResultSet before using it again.

By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. When you use the ResultSet for another query, it will close the existing one internally and create a new one. The first ResultSet object will not be accessible.

You can close all the existing connections in the **finally** block:

```
try{
    //your code here
}
catch{
    //your code here
}
finally{
    rs.close();
    pst.close();
    conn.close();
}
```